# Custom UIImageView Class that adds shadow and make image round in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to create a custom UIImageView class that accomplishes two things, it makes the image view round and add a shadow to it.

This is what i have:

**RoundImage.swift**

```
class RoundImage: UIImageView {
     override func awakeFromNib() {

      }


      func setImageAndShadow(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        print("Image size \(self.frame.size)")
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3.0)
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        layer.shadowRadius = 4

    }

}
```

**ViewController.Swift**

```
Class ViewController : UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: RoundImage!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
      self.userImageView.setImageAndShadow(image: User.sharedInstance.profileImage!)
   }

}
```

As a result of this a get a round image in the app, but there's no shadow in it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3** You can use CAShapeLayer:

```
 func setImageAndShadow(image: UIImage, myView : UIView) {
    self.image = image
    self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    print("Image size \(self.frame.size)")
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2

    let Shape = CAShapeLayer()
    let myPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.frame)

    Shape.shadowPath = myPath.cgPath
    Shape.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    Shape.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    Shape.shadowRadius  = 7
    Shape.shadowOpacity = 0.7


    myView.layer.insertSublayer(Shape, at: 0)

}
```

and in VC

```
let image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4040.jpg")

self.userImageView.setImageAndShadow(image: image!, myView : view)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the shadow because it is cropped with cornerRadius. In order to make it visible you should create a UIView with UIImageView inside, apply cornerRadius to UIImageView and shadow to it's container (superview)